# not a valid way to use push()?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an array from a string input with some
conditions. 
It doesn't seem like this a valid way to use push, as it's not return an array of just numbers.

```js
    function evaluate(input){ 
        function isOperator(ops){
            if(ops == '+' || ops == '*'){
                return true;
            } return false;
        }
        var stack = [];
        for(var char in input){
            if(!isOperator(char)){
                stack.push(input[char]);
            }
        } 
        return stack;
    }
    console.log(evaluate('7+**8'));
```

Comment: Is char a reserved keyword, I forgot whether it is or not

Comment: `for ... in` enumerates object properties, not arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/375399

Comment: @kcuhcx2—no, it's not. [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-reserved-words) has been online forever.

Comment: You could just use `input.replace(/[*+]/g,'').split('')`. ;-)

Comment: You could improve your question by specifying what output you're looking for.

Comment: Or if you want all and only numbers, `input.match(/\d/g);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is testing whether the *index* is an operator. It's not because indexes are always numbers.

```
if(!isOperator( char )){   // char => 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
//              ^^^^
```

While the next line uses the index to access the individual character from the `input` string:

```
stack.push( input[char] ); // input[char] => '7', '+', '*', '*', '8'
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

This would be a good time to rename the variable to avoid the confusion.

```
for (var index in input) {
    var char = input[index];
    if (!isOperator(char)) {
        stack.push(char);
    }
}
```

Also, changing the type of loop to [one more suited for ordered collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea).

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of issues with your code.

`for(var char in input)` doesn't do what you want. It iterates over it like an object. Use `for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)`. It wouldn't be as efficient, but you could also do `input.split().reduce(...)`.

`input[char]` will result in `undefined` since `input['c']` or the like won't exist. However, switching to `i` as the index will fix that.

```
function evaluate(input){ 
    function isOperator(ops){
        if(ops == '+' || ops == '*'){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    var stack = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        var char = input[i];
        if(!isOperator(char)){
            stack.push(char);
        }
    } 
    return stack;
}
console.log(evaluate('7+**8'));
```

Or, with `reduce`:

```
return input.split().reduce(function (stack, value) {
    if (isOperator(value)) {
        return stack;
    }
    return stack.concat(value);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function evaluate(input){ 
    function isOperator(ops){
        if(ops == '+' || ops == '*'){
            return true;
        } return false;
    }
    var stack = [];
    for(var char in input){
        if(!isOperator(char)){
            stack.push(input[char]);
        }
    } 
    return stack;
}
console.log(evaluate('7+**8'));
```

This should work assuming you're trying to do what I think. You cant do an associative array like that in JS but other than that it looks fine. Make sure you know what variables you're calling.

Comment: "*This should work…*"? An answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not even checking whether the inputs are `"+"` or `"*"`. You are simply returning `false` from the `isOperator(ops)` method because your for loop is just counting the `input` values index from `evaluate(input)` method. So you need to fix it so it checks the `"+"` and `"*"` operators.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you want?

```
[
  "7",
  "8"
]
```

If so, others have ably explained the issues with the syntax: `for key in obj` iterates over objects, not arrays. You could use a regular `for` loop if you want to iterate the string as an array in the "traditional" way:

```js
function evaluate(input) {
  var output = [];
  for (var n = 0; n < input.length; n++) {
    if (! (input[n] === '*' || input[n] === '+'))  output.push(input[n]);
  }
  return output;
}
console.log(evaluate('7+**8'));
```

But you don't have to. If you just want all numbers and no operators, then this might win the [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) challenge:

```js
function evaluate(input) {
  return input.match(/\d/g); 
}
console.log(evaluate('7+**8'));
```